# As400 run a personal JRE

Tags: java, performance, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

i have a java program that must run on an as400, running it from qshel run jre 1.6, but my dependencies require jre 1.8 is it possible to start that program with portable 1.8 jre?
as is also done on Windows and Linux with the .bat and .sh files!

can you tell me the commands to customize the (java home) without moving the 1.6 installed?

Comment: are yo able to download?

Comment: Yes have all permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, the only JVMs available for the IBM i platform come from IBM. These are available through various options of the 5770-JV1 product. Versions up to 1.8 are available for IBM i 7.1 and up (perhaps earlier, but I haven't gone digging) You can find the available JVM options at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1117869

To use a Java 1.8 64-bit VM from QSH, you could do eg.

```
JAVA_HOME=/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk80/64bit
export JAVA_HOME
java -jar ...
```

Comment: how download the jvm, sorry im new in as400

Comment: 5770-JV1 comes with the IBM i OS install media. If you don't have that, it should be available through IBM Entitled System Support (ESS). You'll have to have your entitlement information in order to download it an depending on how you purchased and licensed the OS it varies how it shows up under ESS.

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is a very common task in legacy systems.

This worked for me:

- Put your portable jre.zip close to your java program.
- Unzip it
- Create a JAVA_HOME just for this execution:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mydownloads/jre
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

- Try with `java -version`
- Execute your java program: `java -jar myapp.jar`

You could add this steps to yous bash scripts.

Comment: yes in bash it would work but the syntax in as400 which would it be?

Comment: same commands work in QSH and QP2TERM... see also `ADDENVVAR` CL command